# which UITabBarController event to reload a view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've got a window with a UITabBarcontroller at the bottom.  I have 3 tabs, corresponding to their respective views.

Everytime I switch to a view via tapping on the tab, i want it to reload.  Which event do I need to tap into?  Where would I do this?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:` ?